# Does Powershell have an Aggregate/Reduce function?

Tags: powershell

I realize there are related questions, but all the answers seem to be work-arounds that avoid the heart of the matter. Does powershell have an operation that can use a scriptblock to aggregate elements of an array into a single value? This is what is known in other languages as `aggregate` or `reduce` or `fold`.

I can write it myself pretty easily, but given that its the base operation of any list processing, I would assume there's something built in I just don't know about.

So what I'm looking for is something like this

```
1..10 | Aggregate-Array {param($memo, $x); $memo * $x}
```

Comment: @Andie2302 ... no. I'm not sure how `+` fits my criteria? An `aggregate` function is - like I said - key to all list processing, it can actually be used very easily to construct all the other functions such as map, filter, groupby, foreach, etc

Comment: I would love to have the time to do a nice pretty answer, but I don't. See if this article heads you down a useful path: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/12/23/simplifying-data-manipulation-in-powershell-with-lambda-functions/

Comment: Why not use `Measure-Object`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19170783/58553

Comment: @Peter because that only provides a few of the different use cases that reduce is used for, whereas reduce itself can be used for just about any array manipulation

Comment: @GeorgeMauer that is true but `Measure-Object` has the most common ones so i think it should at least be mentioned, and in my case it was just what i needed, and if other people google the same thing i did they will now find this comment!

Comment: Thats a good argument @Peter maybe add it as an answer?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is not anything so obviously named as Reduce-Object but you can achieve your goal with Foreach-Object:

```
1..10 | Foreach {$total=1} {$total *= $_} {$total}
```

BTW there also isn't a Join-Object to merge two sequences of data based on some matching property.

Comment: This is very clever! It fixed up some code I'm writing very nicely.

Answer (score 12):

If you need Maximum, Minimum, Sum or Average you can use `Measure-Object` sadly it dosen´t handle any other aggregate method.

`Get-ChildItem | Measure-Object -Property Length -Minimum -Maximum -Average`

Answer (score 7):

This is something I wanted to start for a while. Seeing this question, just wrote a `pslinq` (https://github.com/manojlds/pslinq) utility. The first and only cmdlet as of now is `Aggregate-List`, which can be used like below:

```
1..10 | Aggregate-List { $acc * $input } -seed 1
#3628800
```

Sum:

```
1..10 | Aggregate-List { $acc + $input }
#55
```

String reverse:

```
"abcdefg" -split '' | Aggregate-List { $input + $acc }
#gfedcba
```

PS: This is more an experiment

Comment: neato. Does it really have to be c# though? I'm pretty sure you can inject variables into a scope from PS (whatever psake does for example). I like c#, but seems a shame to mix paradigms for something like this.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - True. I wanted to do this in C# however, nothing else :)

Answer (score 6):

Ran into a similar issue recently. Here's a pure Powershell solution. Doesn't handle arrays within arrays and strings like the Javascript version does but maybe a good starting point.

```
function Reduce-Object {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias("reduce")]
    [OutputType([Int])]
    param(
        # Meant to be passed in through pipeline.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                    ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [Array] $InputObject,

        # Position=0 because we assume pipeline usage by default.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                    Position=0)]
        [ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
                    Position=1)]
        [Int] $InitialValue
    ) 

    begin {
        if ($InitialValue) { $Accumulator = $InitialValue }
    }

    process {
        foreach($Value in $InputObject) {
            if ($Accumulator) {
                # Execute script block given as param with values.
                $Accumulator = $ScriptBlock.InvokeReturnAsIs($Accumulator,  $Value)
            } else {
                # Contigency for no initial value given.
                $Accumulator = $Value
            }
        }
    }

    end {
        return $Accumulator
    }
}

1..10 | reduce {param($a, $b) $a + $b}
# Or
reduce -inputobject @(1,2,3,4) {param($a, $b) $a + $b} -InitialValue 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a functional module I came upon https://github.com/chriskuech/functional that has a reduce-object, also merge-object, test-equality, etc.  It's surprising that powershell has map (foreach-object) and filter (where-object) but not reduce.  https://medium.com/swlh/functional-programming-in-powershell-876edde1aadb  Even javascript has reduce for arrays.  A reducer actually is very powerful.  You can define map and filter in terms of it.

```
1..10 | reduce-object { $a * $b }

3628800
```

Measure-object can't sum [timespan]'s:

```
1..10 | % { [timespan]"$_" } | Reduce-Object { $a + $b } | ft

Days Hours Minutes Seconds Milliseconds
---- ----- ------- ------- ------------
55   0     0       0       0
```

Merge two objects:

```
@{a=1},@{b=2} | % { [pscustomobject]$_ } | Merge-Object -Strategy fail

b a
- -
2 1
```

Comment: Just eyeballing it, Chris' Powershell implementation of Reduce looks better than my own. The scriptblock validation and use of closures is interesting.