# How can I find minimum execution time in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, time

I have been using `Measure-Command` in PowerShell to time the execution of a Python script:

```
Measure-Command{C:\Python27\python.exe script.py}
```

This displays the execution time in a number of forms, including `TotalSeconds`.

In order to minimize the effect of overhead, I would like to run the script 10 times and find the minimal `TotalSeconds` value across the 10 runs. Is there a simple way to do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Measure-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965.aspx) command, like in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170408/powershell-max-first-aggregate-functions):

```
C:\PS> 1..10 | % { Measure-Command { C:\Python27\python.exe script.py } } | Measure-Object -Minimum

Count    : 3
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 00:00:00.0095165
Property :
```

Comment: It looks like the `Measure-Object` command needs to be `Measure-Object -Minimum TotalSeconds`, but otherwise this works well. Thanks.